# my bootstrap module wont load

Tags: html, css

Can you please see why my module does not load? The module is loaded under . When I call it in the third last column. When I test this code it wont work. Can you help me to see what went wrong? Thank you.

Stefan

[image: my bootstrap folder structure]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="title-logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
<h1 class="title-super text-thin">Stefan Schwarzer</h1>
<h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <hr>
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/2_1140x350.png">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h2 class="text-muted">Featured Work</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/1_350x150.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="project1">
        <h3 clss="text-uppercase">Javascript Project</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/2_350x150.png">
        <h3 clss="text-uppercase">my Hobbies</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com">my Hobbies</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <h3 clss="text-uppercase">my Work</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com"></a>my Work</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Javascript Project</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        hello how are you
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that will work, happy coding

```
<button type="button" class="btn register-now btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">Save changes</button>

    <div id="register" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header register-now">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Save Changes here</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                hello how are you
                    ...
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I dont think it is the modal which needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the current directory for your libraries using "./"

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I added ./ but it still wont load the module. The button pops up but when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: ah I missed a small minor detail for your jquery script. See the new answer